# Организация полей переменного количества.

Tags: база-данных, проектирование

При проектирование БД постоянно натыкаюсь на одну и ту же проблему реализации.
Возьмем к примеру анкету с данными: Фио, Дата рождения, Хобби.

[image]

В данном случае хобби является перечисление с неизвестным заранее количеством, у кого-то их три, а у кого-то десять. Согласно правилам проектирования надо исключить перечисление всех хобби в одном поле и создать новую таблицу, связав ее с полем хобби один ко многим. Этот подход удобен, когда ведется поиск анкетировавшихся по хобби к примеру.

[image]

Если в среднем у человека три разных хобби, то мы получаем на миллион анкетных записей три миллиона записей хобби. А если мы берем анкету, у который таких полей пять и в каждом может быть в среднем десять значений? Получается, вместо одного миллиона записей с полем перечисления, я получаю еще в довесок пять таблиц с десятью миллионами записей.

Я так предполагаю, что БД отлично с этим справляется без значимой потери производительности, только растет объем, но не знаю наверняка. Отсюда вопрос, такая организация записей является нормальной или есть другие подходы и методы решения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Честно говоря, не особо понятен ваш подход, и каким образом вы получаете

> вместо одного миллиона записей с полем перечисления, я получаю еще в довесок пять таблиц с десятью миллионами записей

Самый логичный и напрашивающийся способ решения - это создать таблицу с перечислением хобби и таблицу-связку между анкетами и хобби, в которой будут содержатся записи, в которых хранится идентификатор анкеты и и идентификатор хобби. Эта таблица позволит вам вполне гибко сопоставлять одну анкету с любым количеством хобби, и не будет необходимости плодить какие бы то ни было лишние таблицы.

Comment: Вопрос как раз заключается в этой таблице-связке. Если пользователь ввел десять хобби в одной анкете, сколько записей появится в этой таблице-связке? Десять, я так понимаю. В итоге получается на одну анкету появилось десять записей. Миллион таких анкет - 10 * миллион записей в таблице связке.

Если у меня в анкете будет не только хобби, а еще что-то, то такие таблицы-связки будут катастрофически разрастаться. Вот я и думаю, это нормально или нет, или придется с этим мириться ради выгоды хранения.

Comment: а в чем проблема-то? Это вполне нормально. 10 млн записей (которые в принципе не содержат другой информации кроме внешних ключей) - это не так много, как вам кажется. В крайнем случае, если уж очень над вами довлеет вопрос размеров этих таблиц, то можете сделать что-то вроде битовой маски, которая будет представлять каждое хобби в виде одного бита в некоем числе. Не думаю, что это хорошо (в общем-то тоже нарушение 1НФ), но все же гораздо лучше, чем хранить в виде одной строки

Comment: Описанная в ответе организация меня устраивает. Просто не работал с большими объемами, поэтому возникают вопросы, правильно ли это и не таит ли подобная организация каких-нибудь проблем с ростом записей. Может есть что-то лучше или на что обратить внимание.

Answer (score 0):

А для чего нужны вам эти "хобби"? Если только для того, чтобы вывести в профиле, то может просто хранить в одной строку, разделенные каким-нибудь символом? Даже если надо будет искать всех пользователей у которых есть хобби "спорт" — поиск подстроки не проблема.

Если кроме названия хобби нужно что-то еще, то конечно лучше отдельной таблицей.

Comment: @semigradsky вы слышали когда-нибудь о [нормализации баз данных][2] вообще и о [первой нормальной форме][1] в частности?

[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CF%E5%F0%E2%E0%FF_%ED%EE%F0%EC%E0%EB%FC%ED%E0%FF_%F4%EE%F0%EC%E0
[2]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: @DreamChild  
знаю, что не в тему в клинюсь, но мне на последней паре по базам данных это рассказывали) 1 курс)

Comment: @semigradsky, данный пример чисто гипотетический, для демонстрации. А хранение данных в одной строке в обход первой нормальной формы мне не раз выходило боком.

Немного утрируя, вполне возможно нарваться на такое дело: если у кого-то будет "санный спорт" и "лыжный спорт", то поиск просто "спорт" без них может оказаться затруднительным в рамках SQL.